# how can we set the column data vertically for different sets of column through Pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a use case wherein I have 7 columns. But 1st 4 columns are in one DF and rest 3 in 2nd DF. Below is the sample code where I have defined them

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': [1, 2, 3],
    'col2': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'col3': [4.5, 6.7, 8.9],
    'col4': ['X', 'Y', 'Z']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col5': ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry'],
    'col6': [10, 20, 30],
    'col7': [True, False, True]
})
# Concatenate vertically
result_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)

# Save to Excel
result_df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

So, I want to insert the data in below format

[image]

But ,no matter what I do I am not able to get this format. I actual output is as below

[image]

It seems more of a Pandas limitations to me. I there any work around to achieve the required result.? please suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use `concat` (which will create a single DataFrame), but rather **write the two DataFrames independently**.

Use [`pandas.ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) to handle the file:

```
# create new excel file
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')

# write first DataFrame
df1.to_excel(writer, index=False)

# we start to write after the first table
# skipping 1 row (= len(df)+2)
df2.to_excel(writer, startrow=len(df1)+2, index=False)

# close file
writer.close()
```

[image]

##### generalization

If you have many dataframes you can generalize with:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df1, df2]
skip = 1

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
start = 0
for df in dfs:
    df.to_excel(writer, startrow=start, index=False)
    start += len(df)+skip+1

writer.close()
```

*NB. this is assuming the columns only have **one** level.*

Output:

[image]

For a MultiIndex you must also save the index:

```
dfs = [df1, df2, pd.concat({'extra_level': df1}, axis=1), df1, df2]
skip = 1

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
start = 0
for df in dfs:
    df.to_excel(writer, startrow=start, index=True)
    start += len(df)+skip+df.columns.nlevels+(df.columns.nlevels>1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You nailed it man